# Combine two variables into one input attribute JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I have a input field

```
<input required id={'odds' + index} type="text" step="any" className="form-control validate" value={this.state.odds + ' ' + index} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Where I'm trying to combine the value attribute

```
value={this.state.odds + ' ' + index}
value={this.state.odds + index}
value={this.state.odds`${index}`}
value={this.state.odds `${index}`}
```

I tried all these, but it didn't work. How do you combine a state and a index in an array map?

Expected result: this.state.odds0 where index is 0 and it calls the state element

Example of what I'm getting:

this.state.odds is set to 1.5

this.state.odds0 is set to 5

If index is 0 I get ' 1.5 0 ' or ' 1.50 ' with the commands over. I want to get ' 5 '.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". And show what you are currently getting

Comment: _I wanna call this.state.odds0 etc_ wait what?

Comment: Updated, understand now? @Yousaf

Comment: yes i do understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the desired result because `this.state.odds` returns a number and you are trying to join it with another number by string concatenation but that will just give you a string. It won't get the value you want from the `state`

To get the required value from the state, try

```
value={this.state['odds' + index]}
```

Comment: Object.keys(this.state)[0] returns the first variable I have in my state which is another one, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong approach, you can't put JavaScript code on the value attribute directly on the HTML, instead you should change it from a script tag.

Let me give you an example:

1. We first create our input element on or HTML, note the `id` atrribute, it should be unique across all elements of your HTML document or it will not work properly.

```
<input id="changeThisToYourUniqueID">
```

2. Then we create another element, the script element, this is where we will manipulate our code.

```
<script></script>
```

3. We write the javascript code inside the script element, setting the value of the object to be the sum of the constant and the index.

```
<script>
    let timesWeWantToLoop = 3
    for(let index = 0; index < timesWeWantToLoop; index++){
        document.getElementById("changeThisToYourUniqueID").value = "holamigos!"+index;
    }
</script>
```

The change will happen very fast, so if you really need to see the change happening you can use a recursive function adding a delay to it with the native JavaScript setTimeout() function.

```
<input id="changeThisToYourUniqueID">
<script>
  let index = 0;
  let timesWeWantToLoop = 3
  function myLoop() {
    document.getElementById("changeThisToYourUniqueID").value = "holamigos!"+index;
    setTimeout(function() {
      index++;
      if (index < timesWeWantToLoop) {
        myLoop();
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
  myLoop()
</script>
```

Note: The example will not work under variable input situations, on those cases you need to create an event listener to see when the input value changes.

Cheers!

Comment: OP is using react

Comment: @Yousaf, he asked for JS, not react, but thanks for pointing out.